# Refactoring JDK 8 code to remove redundant methods calls

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following piece of code extracted from a JSF/@Named bean, that I would like to optimize in some way.

```
public List<MyObject> findObjectsByLanguage(String language) {

    return postProcess(webFacade.findObjectsByLanguage(language));
}


public List<MyObject> findRandomObjects(String language) {
    return postProcess(webFacade.findRandomObjectsByLanguage(language));
}

// many other similar methods that invoke postProcess
// ......
// ....

private List<MyObject> postProcess(List<MyObject> myObjects) {

    myObjects().forEach(

        (MyObject o) -> {
            // process and modify object
        }               
    );
    return myObjects;
}
```

The `webFacade` is an EJB, and some post processing on the received entity is needed before passing to the .xhtml page.

This code works perfectly, but I am thinking if there's some special functionality or pattern in JDK 8 that can helps in rewriting the code and remove the `postProcess()`. Also, I have tagged the question with JSF, although it is not strictly a jsf question, maybe there's something that CDI or JSF could do.

Main problem here is that I cannot modify the EJB and therefore the developer should remember to wrap the method call with `postProcess`, which is not the best approach.

I am thinking about something similar to Servlet Filter and so on.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: uhm...I didn't even know the existence of this Code Review, thanks

Comment: @Progman This question would likely be closed on Code Review, because big parts of it is just example code. Please see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/31562

Comment: You could only adapt MyObject, what is ugly too and probably not possible as well. You might transport the original table to your own table and entities, with the entire sync problematics.

Comment: This depends on the API of `webFacade`, i.e. whether it is capable of returning a stream of `MyObject` instead of a `List`. However, there is nothing wrong with this code. It doesn’t have code duplication, as it delegates to a method containing the common operation, which is a reasonable approach. It’s very unlikely that rewriting it will bring any benefit.